# Gitlab base url

Tags: http, nginx, https, config, gitlab

I'm running Gitlab behind an Apache HTTPD SSL proxy
So, Gitlab is running on http://example.com:80 and my proxy is serving this from https://example.com:443.
Currently when I request password reset emails they provide a link to http://example.com not https://example.com

Does anyone know how to change the base URL to https://example.com while still running the gitlab instance over http?

Thanks,

Adam

Answer (score 0):

Enable https in the gitlab.yml file? https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/dbd88d453b8e6c78a423fa7e692004b1db6ea069/config/gitlab.yml.example#L20

Comment: If I do that then Gitlab runs the SSL. I want Apache to run the SSL instead.

Comment: Using Apache is possible but not something we support officially.

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible.
See: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/settings/nginx.md#supporting-proxied-ssl

Setting `nginx['listen_https'] = false` should do the trick.